# Validate SSL Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to connect my c# client to a node.js server via tls/ssl. The Server is working and I have created my certs. But If I want to connect via TcpClient to the Server, it says, that the Certificate is invalid. Could you make your own validation for that cert? Do you guys have any ideas?

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TcpClient _TcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", 8000);
        private static SslStream stream;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            stream = new SslStream(_TcpClient.GetStream());
            stream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            int bytes = -1;
            do
            {
                bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
                decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
                data.Append(chars);
                if (data.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            while (bytes != 0);
            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

The Certificate is self signed so I have to send it with the client, but I dont know how. Even if I disable the validation via `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`
, it does not work (I just put it in the first line of the main method).

Comment: See codeproject source code : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL

Comment: So do you mean the c++ part? :D Or how I install a certificate?

Comment: Sorry.  There are a bunch of codeprojects for SSL and I chose a c++ instead of a c# project.  Try this one : https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=326574

Answer (score 0):

So, I just didn't change the code, I just installed the certificate on my server with this guide: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730672.aspx